# Python Hive Client pyhs2: How to return results from a select statement?

Tags: python, hive

Below is my code:

```
 import pyhs2

 with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism="PLAIN",
               user='biuser',
               password='biuser',
               database='default') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:

        #Execute query
        cur.execute("select * from some_table")
        print "executed"
        #Fetch table results
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
```

This above code continues to run after printing "executed" with no end in sight! Is it supposed to take so much time? Other executions like getting the various database names and getting all table names don't take much time. How do you capture the results of a select statement here?

Comment: Depends. How big is the table? Try to limit your select.

Comment: It is a pretty big table. I actually do need all the results from the table and I want to write the output to a csv file so that I can do further analysis on it. Which is why I'm running a select * from table command. That is the only reason that I need to connect to hive right now.
I have noticed that even for a small table size, the script goes on running.

Comment: Does it print the results?

Comment: Nope! It doesn't print anything, not while running a select command

Comment: What type of queries do work? What is the result of them? If you add a LIMIT 100 in the above SELECT does it work? It should be rather fast. How big is your table in rows/columns?

Comment: I need to get the entire table into a csv file. So as far as I understand, it has to be a select * from table command.

Comment: The use of LIMIT is just for getting insight about the time it takes.

Comment: You could try `fetchone` instead of `fetch`.

Comment: fetchone does return one row of result. Thank you for that. But it still doesn't solve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you; replace your for loop with:

```
while cur.hasMoreRows:
    print cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: I had the same issue as the original question and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get data out of hive you could alternatively try something like this:

```
hive -e 'select * from table' | sed 's/yourdelimiter/,/g' > output.csv
```

What is your delimiter depends on your setup, you could try with `[\t]` or `[\01]` for example.

If you want to run it through a python script you could change the redirection to point to it:

```
hive -e 'select * from table' | sed 's/yourdelimiter/,/g' > myscript.py
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it could do the job.

Comment: I need to do it through a Python script.

Comment: You could try the redirection through a python script, though it might not work depending on your memory and table size.